# KnockoutJS ordering component loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

The home page to my site is loading 7 knockoutjs components. One of the seven components has many slow ajax calls to the api. For some reason the other six components wait for the slow component to complete before making their own ajax calls. Is there a way to force loading that component after the other six?

Comment: Can't give you any meaningful information without seeing some of your code.

Comment: For a start, it may be better not to put your API calls in the component. A central service provider can provide both API calls and help you ensure the correct order is maintained.